# Android Studio Errors when device is connected

Tags: android, android-studio

When I connect my android device to test an app a list of errors come in android studio logcat even before I run the app. 
The error list go on as

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors probably **do not** refer to your app. You can safely ignore then and proceed to your development.

Pro-tip: Use filters on your logcat to see only the messages generated by your app.

**EDIT:** Ok, I've got your question wrong... Try: Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration active.

Comment: No. I can't test the app. App runs in the phone. But it says "no debuggable application" in android  studio and error list comes continuously.

Comment: Can't you run your app? Is the option disabled?

Comment: I can run the app. It runs on the phone. But it is not shown as a debuggable app in android studio.